# adb shell: cannot copy files: Read-only file system

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have rooted my nexus-7 and everything is working smooth except that I am enable to copy files:

```
./sdcard# cp myfile.conf /etc/.
```

or create folders:

```
.# mkdir usr
```

within the root folder.

Searching on the internet, nothing seems to be working .. I tried to change the *chmod*, but it show me this:

```
Read-only file system
```

so, I tried to mount */myfile.conf* and make it read/write as follow:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /sdcard/myfile.conf
```

but it gives me:

```
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

I am browsing and doing everything on my tablet through the ADB from my PC .. so am I doing something wrong .. or am I missing anything ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I saw this article before .. but unfortunately it not helping .. and my problem is exactly how to make the file system writable !! .. it seems no solution is working .. that is why I put this question ..

Comment: You need to read it much more carefully.  Mount applies to *filesystems* not individual files.  Plus, you are trying to change the properties of the source, the actual problem is that your destination /etc may be read only.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: ok .. I will read again thoroughly ..

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thanks .. it is copying now .. I was doing lot of things wrong .. for example I was mounting the file not the _filesystem_ as you said .. i was mounting the wrong folder and not the _/etc_ .. besides, the command itself was syntax-ly wrong .. do u think I should delete this question ?